# How do I let multiple Threads paint onto an AWT component?

Tags: java, multithreading, graphics, paint, mandelbrot

EDIT: solved, look below for my solution.

first of all, this is my very first question here, so if I make any mistakes, please tell me.

I am trying to write a Mandelbrot Fractal Program in Java, for training purposes. The ideal for all the functionality I want to have is the Fractalizer (http://www.fractalizer.de/en/), but for now, I will be happy with a program that draws the Mandelbrot Set on the screen (instead of, for example, writing it to an image file). Of course, I want the program to be fast, so I thought that I could split the calculation into multiple threads to utilize my multi-core processor; for example, on a quad-core system, the image would be divided into 2x2=4 images, each to be calculated by a separate thread. All these threads get a Graphics object passed on which they draw the pixels as they are calculated.

My first attempt to get this working was to have the threads draw on a BufferedImage.getGraphics() and to have the paint() method constantly call repaint() as long as the image isn't finished:

```
g.drawImage(tempImg, 0, 0, null);
if (waiterThread.isAlive())
{
    try
    {
        Thread.sleep(10);
    } catch (InterruptedException e)
    {
        // do nothing
    }
    repaint(10);
}
```

(waiterThread joins all calculating threads one after another, so as long as the waiterThread is alive, at least one calculating thread is not yet finished.)

This works, but causes ugly flickering on the canvas because of the frequent repainting.

Then, by means of a small test program, I found out that Graphics.draw*anything* draws on the screen instantly, before the paint method returns, so my current approach is the following:

- One Panel with a GridLayout that contains 2x2 (on a <4-core system, 1x1) MandelbrotCanvas objects
- Each MandelbrotCanvas object will, on the first paint() call, initialize a calculating Thread, pass its own Graphics object to it (actually, I'm using a custom GroupGraphics class that passes one Graphics call to several graphics, to "backup" the image into a BufferedImage.getGraphics(), but that's not important), and start the calculating thread.
- The panel will in its paint() method fetch the calculating threads from each of the MandelbrotCanvases and join() them.

Unfortunately, this creates only a black screen. Only when calculation is finished, the image is displayed.

What is the right way to have several threads paint onto one component?

EDIT:

What I didn't know: Only the Event Dispatch Thread is allowed to paint on AWT components (roughly spoken), which means that the last approach above can't possibly work - apparently, it's supposed to throw an exception, but I didn't get one. My solution is to use the first approach - draw the image onto a BufferedImage and draw that onto the Canvas - with the only modification that I overload the update() method to call the paint() method *without clearing the painting area*:

```
public void update(Graphics g)
{
    paint(g);
}
```

So I guess my answer to the general question ("How do I let multiple Threads paint onto an AWT component?") would be: You can't, it's not allowed. Let the Threads draw onto a BufferedImage.getGraphics(), and draw that image repeatedly. Overload the update() method like above to avoid flickering. (It looks really great now.) Another tip that I can't use in my case, but is still good, is that there is a variant of repaint() that takes rectangle arguments to specify the area that has to be redrawn, and a variant that takes a time argument (in milliseconds), so the repaint doesn't have to happen immediately.

EDIT2: This link provides very helpful information: http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/painting/index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only the GUI thread can paint directly on your component.

So you must call the repaint method.

When you have background computation, to force a fast drawing, you should use the [version taking a time as parameter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#repaint%28long%29).

Some details from [here](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/painting/index.html) :

> NOTE: If multiple calls to repaint() occur on a component before the
>   initial repaint request is processed, the multiple requests may be
>   collapsed into a single call to update(). The algorithm for
>   determining when multiple requests should be collapsed is
>   implementation-dependent. If multiple requests are collapsed, the
>   resulting update rectangle will be equal to the union of the
>   rectangles contained in the collapsed requests.

Comment: so the AWT will just ignore Graphics.drawLine() etc. calls that do not come from the EDT?

Comment: Normally you should have an exception when the Graphics is one of a component. But you may simply have a delay problem, with all repaint being postponed until the CPU is free.

Comment: okay, i went with my first approach, only with the difference that I overloaded the update() method to _not_ clear the drawing area. Thanks for your help!

Comment: If you think you can't accept an other answer and that your answer is good, please don't let it in the question : make an answer and accept it, that's the normal way and that's cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

You have to send requests to the EDT.

```
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Rectangle r = myCurrentWorkingThread.getFinishedRectangle();
            myPainter.repaint(r);
        }
    });
```

The idea is that you won't repaint pixel by pixel, rather giving larger chunks to the worker-threads. As soon as they're finished with a unit of work, they notify the main object (myPainter) that would do the actual work. This construct (EventQueue.invokeLater) will guarantee that it will be on the Event Dispatcher Thread.