# My TimerTask Function cannot update the label.setText

Tags: java, javafx, timertask

Im writing a small program that involves a timer but for some reason I cant get the TimerTask to update the value of my Label.setText

```
public class Main extends Application  {


Label TimerLabel;
/* Create a Button named button */
Button button;
/* Create three Radiobuttons named Radio1,Radio2,Radio3 */
RadioButton Radio1, Radio2, Radio3;

Timer QuestionTimer = new Timer();
TimerTask QuestionTick = new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        TimerLabel.setText(String.valueOf(Integer.valueOf(TimerLabel.getText())+1));
    }
};

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

/*UI Part*/
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {


    /*Window(Stage) Title is set to "Try 1"*/
    primaryStage.setTitle("Try 1");

    /*Button properties*/
    button = new Button();
    button.setText("Click Me");


    //Radio Button
    Radio1 = new RadioButton();
    Radio1.setText("Click Me 1");
    Radio1.setOnAction(e->{
        System.out.println("Radio Button Clicked");
    });

    Radio2 = new RadioButton();
    Radio2.setText("Click Me 2");
    Radio2.setOnAction(e->{
        System.out.println("Radio Button 2 Clicked");
    });

    Radio3 = new RadioButton();
    Radio3.setText("Click Me 3");
    Radio3.setOnAction(e->{
        System.out.println("Radio Button 3 Clicked");
    });

    TimerLabel = new Label();
    TimerLabel.setText("0");


    /*Here my layout is defined */
    Pane Buttonlayout = new Pane();
    button.setLayoutX(200);
    button.setLayoutY(200);
    Radio1.setLayoutX(15);
    Radio1.setLayoutY(20);
    Radio2.setLayoutX(15);
    Radio2.setLayoutY(40);
    Radio3.setLayoutX(15);
    Radio3.setLayoutY(60);
    TimerLabel.setLayoutX(100);
    TimerLabel.setLayoutY(20);
    Buttonlayout.getChildren().add(button);
    Buttonlayout.getChildren().add(Radio1);
    Buttonlayout.getChildren().add(Radio2);
    Buttonlayout.getChildren().add(Radio3);
    Buttonlayout.getChildren().add(TimerLabel);

    /*Here we define the scene (aka everything inside the stage (inside the window))*/
    Scene scene1 = new Scene(Buttonlayout,300,250);


    primaryStage.setScene(scene1);
    primaryStage.show();

    QuestionTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(QuestionTick,1000,1000);
}

}
```

So thats my code, I know most of it seems stupid but I first wanted to start programming on the timer and well it didnt work. Any kind of help would be appreciated

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11224886/how-do-i-let-multiple-threads-paint-onto-an-awt-component) question, Timers have to be considered to be running on another thread.

Answer (score 1):

From the code it appears you are utilizing the `java.util.Timer` class. The documentation states `Implementation note: All constructors start a timer thread.` The the JavaFX UI should not be updated from another thread, which is what you are doing with the timer.

Rather than updating the UI directly use the [Platform.runLater(Runnable)](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/application/Platform.html#runLater%28java.lang.Runnable%29) to schedule the UI tasks on the main JavaFX thread.

```
javafx.application.Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    TimerLabel.setText(String.valueOf(Integer.valueOf(TimerLabel.getText())+1));
  }
}
```

And please, do yourself a favor and get rid of the method chaining. It will make it easier to debug when `Integer.valueOf` throws an `Exception`.

```
String timer_label = TimerLabel.getText();
Integer timer_int = Integer.valueOf(timer_label);
String timer_text = String.valueOf(timer_int + 1);
TimerLabel.setText(timer_text);
```

Comment: Thanks this worked and yes I did not think about the Integer exceptions so I tweaked that bit of the code too.